# I have a strange problem when calling runif in an Rcpp routine

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a routine called test written in Rcpp which has a single argument, a function called g. In the routine I call another Rcpp routine called ru that returns a uniform [0,1]. (The same issue happens with other R random variable routines such as rbinom). I have a small loop that calls ru a few times and prints the result.

If that is all everything works fine. However, if I also make a call to g, the random numbers returned by ru are all the same! Even so g and ru have nothing in common.

Actually this happens only if g is also a Rcpp routine. If it is a R routine everything works as expected. In the example below both fC and fR simple return 0.0.

Here are the routines:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector fC() { return Rcpp::wrap(0.0); }

Rcpp::NumericVector ru() { return Rcpp::runif(1); }                  

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(Rcpp::Function g) { 
      
  Rcpp::Rcout << "first ru" << "\n";
  for(int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector z = g() ;
    Rcpp::Rcout << ru()  <<" ";
  }
  
  Rcpp::Rcout<<"\n\n second ru \n";
  for(int j=0; j<10; ++j) Rcpp::Rcout<< ru() <<" ";
  Rcpp::Rcout<<"\n";
}

/***R
# and the R routine is
fR = function() {0.0}

# Calling the R function works just fine 
set.seed(1)
test(fR)

# but not when the Rcpp function is called
set.seed(1)
test(fC)
*/
```

This produces

```
> test(fR)
first ru
0.265509 0.372124 0.572853 0.908208 0.201682 0.89839 0.944675 0.660798 0.629114 0.0617863 

 second ru 
0.205975 0.176557 0.687023 0.384104 0.769841 0.497699 0.717619 0.991906 0.380035 0.777445 

> set.seed(1)

> test(fC)
first ru
0.265509 0.265509 0.265509 0.265509 0.265509 0.265509 0.265509 0.265509 0.265509 0.265509 

 second ru 
0.372124 0.572853 0.908208 0.201682 0.89839 0.944675 0.660798 0.629114 0.0617863 0.205975
```

In the second call, the first loop with the call to `g` always returns the same number. So somehow a call to `g` seems to set a seed for runif if `g` is an `Rcpp` function, even though `g` does nothing.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you are trying to do.  Rcpp, and that is fairly cleanly documented, protects the RNG settings between the state before and after calling a function add with Rcpp Attributes.  You deliberately jump around that here by calling R function from C.  So maybe this is par for the course -- in any event you _can_ turn the RNG protection off in which the behavior may be different.  But I do not see what the goal here is, really.  Sorry.  Maybe if you reword and I understand what you are after I can help more.

Comment: Wolfgang ; I tweaked your example slightly to make the sampling reproducible and added namespaces *just in case* something weird was going on ... but the same effect.  Having `Rcpp::NumericVector z = g() ;` does seem to effect the random seed when called in the loop ... you can see it stays at the first value

Comment: maybe related; https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/823

Comment: Dirk, in the real problem the routine ru needs to generate a number of random variates from different distributions such as Binomial and Poisson. I might have written these eventually also in C++ (or better found existing routines) but for the moment I thought I would just use the corresponding R routines. And that's when I ran into this issue, which I found strange. Now I understand that it was done on purpose.

Comment: I presume you are unaware of `Rcpp::rbinom()` and `Rcpp::rpois()`.  We also offer the C variants documented in the R manuals in the `R::` namespace.

Comment: No, I know about these Rcpp versions, and I tried those as well, but the problem happens with them also. I suppose I should have used them in my toy example, sorry for that.

Comment: You still have not explained why your C++ function has to call an R function -- creating the problem you at least now know how to avoid using documented function.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the GetRNGstate(); and PutRNGstate(); statements as described in the document does indeed to the trick! Thanks user20650.

The crucial part of the toy example now looks like this:

```
  for(int j=0;j<10;++j) {
     NumericVector z=g();
     GetRNGstate();
     Rcout<<ru()<<" ";
     PutRNGstate();
  }
```